# Firebase cloud function not firing for rewrites

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have rewrites in firebase.json like below

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "function": "addOGForHomepage"
      },
      {
        "source": "/video/**",
        "function": "addDynamicOG"
      },
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

In my cloud function index.js. I have two express instances:

```
const app_homepage = express();
const app_video_page = express();
```

The `addDynamicOG` can fire correctly. The implementation is like below:

```
app_video_page.get("/video/:videoId", async (req, res) => {
    //add dynamic OG for each video and return
})
exports.addDynamicOG = functions.https.onRequest(app_video_page);
```

The `addOGForHomepage` has almost the same code, but it never fired.

```
app_homepage.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    //add OG for homepage
})
exports.addOGForHomepage = functions.https.onRequest(app_homepage);
```

Can anyone tell me how can `addOGForHomepage` be fired in my case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this, first temporarily remove all other rewrites to make sure there isn't a conflict.  Then, if you have a static index.html in your public folder for hosting, temporarily remove that file and see if it works.  Local static content takes [priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order) over rewrites.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I am using reactjs and firebase hosting. Once deployed, the index.html will be created under /build directory. I don't think I can remove it. It would just fail to compile.

Comment: Sounds like you either have some changes to make to that build, or the rewrite path.  The priority used by Firebase Hosting can't be changed.